# What is the last step of this AM-GM proof?

Tags: inequality

If $x$ and $a$ are both positive numbers, what are the arithmetic and geometric means of the numbers $x$ and $\frac{a^{2}}{x}$?

If $x_{1}>0$  and $x_{n}$ is defined by $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n}+\frac{a^{2}}{x_{n}})$, show that $a\leq x_{n+1}\leq x_{n}$, for $n\geq 2$.

Progress:

$AM=\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{a^{2}}{x})$, $GM=a$.

$0\leq (x-a)^{2}$

$\Rightarrow a\leq \frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{a^{2}}{x})$.

$GM \leq AM \Rightarrow a\leq x_{n+1}$.

How do I complete this proof to show $x_{n+1}\leq x_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2(x_{n+1}-x_n)={a^2\over x_n}-x_n\implies 2x_n(x_{n+1}-x_n)=a^2-x_n^2\leq0$$As $a<x_n\ \ \forall n$ (You proved)

Comment: I proved that $a\leq x_{n+1}$ $\forall n$. Does this imply $a\leq x_n$ $\forall n$?

Comment: @shredalert Isn't it obvious?

Comment: nvm. I see it now. I have a tendency to overlook the obvious. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @shredalert #HappyToHelp